# Find and click disabled element in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

### I'm working on automating a website and I'm encountering a problem with finding a single button.

The issue stands that the website, has made a button I want to find and click by Selenium  disabled by default, meaning selenium cannot find it by the xpath selector. I have concluded that the button has an event listener associated with it for mouse-over, meaning that the button becomes enabled and available to interact with **only** if the mouse if over that element.

I have a few solutions but I don't fully like neither of them.

##### Here is what works:

***1. Mouse over that element by relative known position of bigger and encapsulating div element, and then clicking it.***

***2. If you open inspect element, for some odd reason, the element becomes interactable and the html looks normal. But this probably is a security feature from the website, that will easily detect that I'm automating if I use this solution of opening inspect element.***

***3. Using image recognition API for selenium to capture the image of the button and locate it. This is my least favorite, unnecessary complex work for this problem.***

The interesting thing from #2 is that when you try to see the hmtl code, the button and everything appears normal and starts to function, which I find very funny in a way.

I won't show any html code, I hopefully have made everything clear explaining with words.

Any suggestions or ideas to smartly fix this issue will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem. You want to first hover the button and then it will be enabled. Then you can click the element.

The you could try something like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# hover
script = """\
hoverable_element = driver.find_element...
var hoverEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    hoverEvent.initEvent ('mouseover', true, true);
    arguments[0].dispatchEvent (hoverEvent);
"""
driver.execute_script("script", hoverable_element)

# click
click_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))
click_element.click()
```